# i want to get the property count for each zip code

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database with `property_id`, `property_name`,`property_zip`

On a page i load all the zip codes using:

```
<?php include"connection.php";

$checke = "SELECT DISTINCT porperty_zip FROM property_list "; 

$rsd = mysql_query($checke); ?> 

<table width="600" style="font-size:12px; border:1px solid #000000; text-align:center;" cellpadding="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr> 

<td><strong>Zip</strong></td> </tr> 

<?php 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) 

{ ?> 

<tr> <td><h2><?php echo $row['porperty_zip']; ?></h2></td> </tr> 

<?php 

} 

?>
```

Output:

> 92508
>
> 92566

Now can anyone help me  add the property count for each zip code.

I want the output to look like:

> 92508 (15)
>
> 92566 (20)

Comment: I have one more question. 

on another table i save the the registered user details, 

user_id, name, zip 

i also want find, the how many property available for each member. is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SQL like:-

```
SELECT property_zip, COUNT(*) AS property_count FROM property_list GROUP BY property_zip
```

Then you can use

```
<tr> <td><h2><?php echo $row['property_zip']; ?>(<?php echo $row['<?php echo $row['property_count']; ?>']; ?>)</h2></td> </tr>
```

EDIT - To get the number of properties per registered user (assuming the table is registered_user_details):-

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.name, a.zip, COUNT(b.property_zip) AS PropertiesForUser
FROM registered_user_details a
LEFT OUTER JOIN property_list b
ON a.zip = b.property_zip
GROUP BY a.user_id, a.name, a.zip
```

Comment: I have one more question.

on another table i save the the registered user details, user_id, name, zip

i also want find, the how many property available for each member.

is it possible

Comment: i am beginner on Php

why a.user_id ?
can u explain it

Comment: OK. This is SQL rather than php. In SQL you can give an alias name to columns and tables. For example in the first bit of SQL we have given the count an alias of "property_count". With the table names I have given them the alias' of a and b, in this case mainly for lazyness as it means less typing! I have put the table alias name in front of the field name to force it to use that field from that table (for example there might be a field called name on both tables). Sometimes you join a table against itself, hence you use a different alias for each 'copy' of the table you are referring to.

Comment: how can i output like 92550 (10), can u able to give me full code for this process

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744482/count-number-of-property-available-for-member-according-to-there-zip-code

i have posted a question

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT property_zip,count(*) as property_count FROM property_list GROUP BY property_zip
```

then in the html:

```
<tr> <td><h2><?php echo $row['property_zip'].'('.$row['property_count'].')'; ?></h2></td> </tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` ...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as property_count, property_zip FROM property_list GROUP BY property_zip
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this query:

```
SELECT 
  porperty_zip ,
  COUNT(*) as nb
FROM property_list
GROUP BY
  porperty_zip
```

And on php side:

```
echo $row['porperty_zip']." ".$row['nb'];
```