# count number of property available for member according to there zip code

Tags: php

i have two table

1) member

- member_id
- name
- address
- zip

2) property

- property_id
- property_name
- property_zip

i want to list all the member zip (without duplicate) and show the count of property for each zip code in a table

---

### Member Zip | Property Count

### 95674      |   50

### 95852      |   90

### 95614      |   0

### 95070      |   5

its have multiple member with same zip code and also multiple property with same zip code

i don't want any repeat on the Member Zip output column.

i have 5 member with 92550 & 10 member with 82475, i have to show

92550
82475

& on property table i have 10 with zipcode 82475 and 4 with zip code 92550.

Final O/P

92550 (4)
82475 (10)

can anyone help me to find it ?

Comment: You want the count of property.property_id for each value of member.member_zip or for each member.member_id (assuming multiple members can have a common zip).  Would each member only be related to properties that match their zip?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: its have multiple member with same zip code and also multiple property with same zip code  

i don't want any repeat on the Member Zip output column.  

i have 5 member with 92550 & 10 member with 82475, i have to show  

92550  
82475

& on property table i have 10 with zipcode 82475 and 4 with zip code 92550.  

Final O/P  

92550 (4)  
82475 (10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT a.zip, COUNT(b.propety_zip)
FROM member a
LEFT JOIN propety b
ON a.zip = b.propety_zip
GROUP BY a.zip
```

Edit

I used your code

```
$checke = "SELECT a.zip, COUNT(b.property_zip) AS property_count FROM member a LEFT JOIN property b ON a.zip = b.property_zip GROUP BY a.zip";
$rsd = mysql_query($checke) or die(mysql_error()); ?> 

<table width="600" style="font-size:12px; border:1px solid #000000; text-align:center;" cellpadding="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr> 
    <td><strong>Zip</strong></td> 
  </tr>
  <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) { ?> 
  <tr> 
    <td><h2><?php echo $row['zip'] . " (" . $row['property_count'] .")"; ?></h2></td> 
 </tr> 
 <?php }  ?>
```

Comment: how can i print the output ?

Comment: @Kannan You don't know how to query the database in PHP?

Comment: @Kannan, how do you use mysql?

Comment: <?php 
include"connection.php";

$checke = "SELECT porperty_zip, COUNT(*) AS property_count FROM property_list GROUP BY porperty_zip"; 
$rsd = mysql_query($checke);
?>
<table width="600" style="font-size:12px; border:1px solid #000000; text-align:center;" cellpadding="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
<td><strong>Zip</strong></td>

  </tr>
  <?php
  //Print the contents
  
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rsd))
  {
   

  ?>
        <tr>
 <td><h2><?php echo $row['porperty_zip']; echo" ("; echo $row['property_count']; echo")"; ?></h2></td>
  </tr>
       <?php
  } //while
  ?>

Comment: i know how to output, but in this code i cannot understand!

i am just a beginner

Comment: ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in F:\wamp\www\LIsing Page\template\admin\demo-code3.php on line 23

its showing error!, i removed "}" from the last line but still showing error

Comment: @kannan Sorry there was something commented, try now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30603/discussion-between-kannan-and-fabio)

Comment: it have a little problem, i have one zip code with 30 property and its showing the count as 60. can u help me to find the error

Comment: i have 2 member with zipcode 91764 and i only have 30 property for that zip code.

but in my output count is 60. now to solve this problem.

Comment: i used pagination from this tutorial http://www.nacodes.com/2013/03/14/Pagination-with-Jquery-PHP-Ajax-and-MySQL